# logarithm exponentiation question

Tags: logarithms

I don't understand how to arrive at the equation that  $\log_{\log n}(n)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\log\log(n)}?$

Comment: Your expression is ambiguous. What is the meaning of the $-1$ and what does it apply to ? By the way, I see no interpretation that would make this identity true.

Comment: to clarify, it's log base logn times n raised to the minus 1

Comment: If possible, please disprove it. Instead of just throwing it out there

Comment: You should realize that you clarified nothing, on the opposite. What is raised ? And what is the argument of the logarithm ?

Comment: Your previous comment is unacceptable. I am not doing all the guesswork and trying all hypothesis when you spend no effort making things clear.

Comment: can never be too sure what people know

Comment: ok somebody already has responded within moments while you were busy complaining lol I'm fine

Comment: I know what an ambiguous expression is, thank you. Behave yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Let's interpret the expression as
$$
x=\log_{\log n}(n^{-1})
$$
where the unadorned “log” denotes the logarithm with respect to an unspecified base. By definition,
$$
(\log n)^x=n^{-1}
$$
so we can take the (unadorned) logarithm
$$
x\log\log n=\log(n^{-1})=-\log n
$$
and therefore
$$
x=-\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}
$$
If instead you want
$$
x=(\log_{\log n}(n))^{-1}
$$
then set $y=x^{-1}$ and get $y=\log_{\log n}(n)$. With a similar technique,
$$
y=\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}
$$
and therefore
$$
x=\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}
$$
In neither case we get the identity you would prove.